# I can't move any apps or downloads to my SD card

Tags: external-sd

After having my phone, a zte, I put a 16 GB SD card in it and had the option of save to SD card. I have downloaded a bunch of apps and music and not realizing until now, that none of it has saved to my SD card. All of it is in the phone. And my phone shows that its reading the SD card and it has nothing stored on it. So I went and tried to move apps and such to the card only to find out that there isn't an option for any of my apps to move to the SD card. I don't know if I have explained very well, I can give more info if needed. But this is perplexing as I've never had this happened before, or I'm doing something wrong and not realising it.

Comment: Are you saving to sdcard0 or to extSdCard? First one is internal storage and second one is SD card.

Comment: I only have two options of saving to phone... Or SD card. I took screenshots to help but as of now, I don't know how/if I can post them.

Comment: If you have both internal and external SD card, App2SD only uses the former (called "primary", as it's always there and not removable). No way to change that without root access. As for downloads, photos, etc, check with the corresponding apps: at least camera apps usually have an option to let you chose the storage location.

Answer (score 0):

One can move files from phone to sdcard by a powerful file manager like total commander. total commander can be downloaded from google play store.

Comment: Can you link it in the post here?